# Internet Explorer 8 duplicate div bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

[on this page](http://euroworker.no/user/checkout) in IE 8, there is the famous phantom element bug. I have researched for two days all possible things I can find that might cause this, including hidden inputs (present) floated elements (not present) and HTML comments `<!--...-->` (present).
[image: ie_phantom_fucking_element]

The "phantom element" is the grey div between the login div and the "ny kunde" button.

When trying to view this is the IE dev tools (F12) it cannot be selected, nor viewed. I believe it is because of a rendering issue in IE8.

Removing these did not help at all. Plus we apparently need the hidden input for form validation.

It's worth mentioning that this eCommerce solution doesn't validate *out of the box*.

I have exhausted every solution I can think of, and it is still present.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly is the "phantom element"? Care to post screen shot?

Comment: Edited with brand new screenshot, for your viewing pleasure. :)

Comment: What does the element inspector say?

Comment: That the element does not exist. It's not in code and you can't select it with the "direct selection" tool.

Comment: I checked with Firebug lite for IE and it says it's not a phantom element, but rather the correct div, stretched to double height. I can't explain the borders around it though o_O. Weirdest thing ever, I tell ye...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting at line 348, there is this code:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="/checkout/selectAddress" />

</form>
</div>
```

If I change it to this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="/checkout/selectAddress" />

</div>
</form>
```

Then the problem is solved.

Simplifying (*removing stuff from*) your HTML:

```
<div id="user-wrapper">
  <form action="/user/doLogin" method="post" id="loginForm" />
  <div id="user-kundelogginn">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can clearly see the `form` tag is being closed inside the `div`.

**How did I figure this out?**

I used the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feuroworker.no%2Fuser%2Fcheckout&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), which got me on the right track with this:

> Line 350, Column 7: end tag for
>   element "form" which is not open

Comment: I also used the validator, but this package throws so many errors I guess I missed it! Thanks :)

Comment: A big THANK YOU, from a random Googler 2 years later with the same problem!